# Solve "missing secure attribute in encrypted session (ssl) cookie" with Java

Tags: java, security, cookies, bluemix-app-scan

Recently, IBM Security AppScan found an issue that missing secure attribute in encrypted session (ssl) cookie. the report is below:

[image]

this app is code by Java and i add a filter to set all cookies secure, code:

```
public class BasicFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    if( cookies != null && cookies.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            cookies[i].setSecure(true);
            cookies[i].setHttpOnly(true);
            resp.addCookie(cookies[i]);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(req,resp);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}
```

}

it's works while all cookies response twice like that and it will try to login over and over(login with **SSO**):

[image]

Thanks for your kindly help and how can i do to enable secure and solve cookie issue, hope you guys can give me some idea to solve this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: additionally, most of the cookies set by single sign-on(sso) and when i test in local,  there is no cookie issue due to i don't enable sso in local, hope this message will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The same question is posted in IBM support forum as well. You should be looking into configuration fix. please look here

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/1505-ifix-po05616-missing-secure-attribute-encrypted-session-ssl-cookie-and-missing-httponly-session-cookie